# Getting a scheduled ID for a resource, like GPU, when using snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I'm using the resources directive for a rule in a snakefile to make sure my rule only uses one of my four GPUs. I need to know which of the 4 available gpus to use in my script however. Is there a way to find out which of the 4 available resources I've been scheduled to use by snakemake?